# Hide an html element with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I would hide an html element when a condition occurs. 
I try to implement this code in coffeescript:

```
if byName == username 
document.#prv-btn.style.display = 'none'
```

I have already tried this code but don't run. 
The element `#prv-btn` is my html element. In my page i have some users and for each of them i have this `#prv-btn`. For example if i have ten users, i have ten `#prv-btn`, but only one i want that i see, each user see the button near his name. 
How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You need to indent the body of `if` clauses in CoffeeScript.
2. You need to use `getElementById()` to actually select the `button` by its ID.

Also, I recommend using jQuery for DOM work such as this. It works just fine with the compiled CoffeeScript.

**Code:**

```
if byName == username 
    document.getElementById("prv-btn").style.display = 'none'
```

Here is a link to a jsFiddle that I made for this: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanporta/tw3nn/1/

Comment: And if i have a button in a div, where the div id change but the button id doesn't change, how can i do? 'document.getElementById("mydiv").getElementById("prv-btn").style.display = 'none'' ??

Comment: You should not use the same ID on multiple buttons. Use a class for that. You should us jQuery if you want to do more than select by ID.

Comment: Also look at `querySelector`